# Inconsistent matrices in SymPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, sympy

I'm calculating reduced echelon forms in SymPy. I'm trying to get the pivot columns of the following matrix:

```
exercise4 = Matrix([[1,3,5,7],[3,5,7,9],[5,7,9,1]])
```

I examine the matrix with the following:

```
exercise4.rref()[0]

Matrix([
[1, 0, -1, 0],
[0, 1,  2, 0],
[0, 0,  0, 1]])
```

...which, as an aside, is different from my NumPy reduced matrix of

```
exercise4 = np.array([[1,3,5,7],[3,5,7,9],[5,7,9,1]])
exercise4[1] = exercise4[1] + -3*exercise4[0]
exercise4[2] = exercise4[2] + -5*exercise4[0]
exercise4[1] = -1/4*exercise4[1]
exercise4[0] = exercise4[0] + -3*exercise4[1]
exercise4[2] = exercise4[2] + 8*exercise4[1]
exercise4

array([[  1,   0,  -1,  -2],
       [  0,   1,   2,   3],
       [  0,   0,   0, -10]])
```

`rref()[1]` here returns `(0, 1, 3)`, the third element of which is obviously incorrect, as it is the last element of augmented matrix. The third row is inconsistent, and there should be no third pivot column.

Is it an inherent flaw of `sympy.Matrix().rref()` that it will incorrectly interpret inconsistent pivot columns? Is that something that I need to be mindful of, or is there some way around this?

Comment: You didn't put your matrix in *reduced* row-echelon form when doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Doing your pivot on [2,3] produces the `rref` matrix:

```
In [269]: M                                                                     
Out[269]: 
array([[  1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2.],
       [ -0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0., -10.]])
In [271]: M[0]-=M[2]*(-2/-10)                                                                                                             
In [276]: M[1]-=M[2]*(3/-10)                                                    
In [278]: M[2]/= -10                                                                                                                    
In [281]: M                                                                     
Out[281]: 
array([[ 1.,  0., -1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  0.],
       [-0., -0., -0.,  1.]])
```

When I plug your matrix into an interactive form, I get the `sympy` result

http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?c=rref

Here too: https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/linear-algebra/reduced-row-echelon-form-rref-caclulator/

This version reduces the last row, so all leading terms are 1.  But one source allows:

https://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=reduced_row_echelon_form

> Note: Some references present a slightly different description of the row echelon form. They do not require that the first non-zero entry in each row is equal to 1.

Comment: Maybe I have a misunderstanding of linear algebra. I just started teaching myself. Am I meant to reduce column `n` despite column `n` being the "answers" of the matrix? In other words, with `Matrix([[1,3,5,7],[3,5,7,9],[5,7,9,1]])`, `[[-2],[3],[-10]]` are the "solutions to the "problems" of `x1 - x3`, `x2 + 2x3`, and `0x1 + 0x2 + 0x3` respectively. Since the final row contains an inconsistent solution, does it still contain a pivot, as the SymPy solution suggests?